# How to get vertices of each face of the 80th Johnson solid?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I am trying to draw the 80th Johnson solid by LaTeX; I tried

```
PolyhedronData[{"Johnson", 80}]
```

and

```
PolyhedronData[{"Johnson", 80}, "Vertices"]
```

To draw this solid, I must determine the vertices of each face. How to find them?

P.S. I use Mathematica 11.2.

Comment: `PolyhedronData[{"Johnson", 8}, {"Vertices", "FaceIndices"}]`

Comment: BTW, I don't see `{"Johnson", 80}` in the output of `PolyhedronData[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{vertices, faceindices} = PolyhedronData[{"Johnson", 80}, {"Vertices", "Faces"}];

Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], Opacity[.7], Polygon[vertices[[#]]]} & /@ faceindices,
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Triangles and rectangles:

```
Row @ Table[Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], Opacity[.7], Polygon[vertices[[#]]]} & /@
     Select[faceindices, Length@# == k &],
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Medium], {k, {3, 4}}]
```

[image]

**Note:** In versions 12.0+, replace `"Faces"` with `"FaceIndices"`.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Unfortunately, concerning its plot, the result of

```
Graphics3D[{Glow[Yellow], EdgeForm[Gray], PolyhedronData["Johnson", "Polygons"]}, Lighting -> None]
```

[image]

is not satisfactory. I followed  the documentation.

Addition. It appears the right command is

```
Graphics3D[{ Glow[Yellow], EdgeForm[Gray], 
PolyhedronData[{"Johnson", 80}, "Polygons"]}, Lighting -> None]
```

[image]
and a simpler command

```
PolyhedronData[{"Johnson", 80}]
```

[image]

produces a nicer result.

Comment: `Graphics3D[{Glow[Yellow], EdgeForm[Gray], 
  PolyhedronData["Johnson", 80]}, Lighting -> None]` produces an empty plot in red.

Comment: The result of `Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Glow[Yellow], EdgeForm[Gray], 
  PolyhedronData["Johnson", "Polygons"]}, Lighting -> None]` is unsatifactory too. I understand there are self-intersections here. Unfortunately, I don't find any example of such kind in the documentation.

Comment: It should be noticed the command `Graphics3D[{Glow[Yellow], EdgeForm[Gray], PolyhedronData["Johnson", "Polygons"]}, Lighting -> None]` produces no messages, but an incorrect plot.